# PHPWord - remove all search-patterns from word document

Tags: preg-match-all, docx, phpword

I'm using PHPWord to read my docx template and remove all search-patterns from the template at the end of the processing. The search-patterns in the docx template is

```
${SOMETAG}
text block
${/SOMETAG}
```

the xml behind the docx has a structure that looks something like this:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00E21534" w:rsidRDefault="00E21534" w:rsidP="00E21534"><w:r><w:t>${SOMETAG}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00E21534" w:rsidRDefault="00E21534" w:rsidP="00E21534"><w:r><w:t>text block</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00E21534" w:rsidRDefault="00E21534" w:rsidP="00E21534"><w:r><w:t>${/SOMETAG}</w:t></w:r></w:p>
```

This is the function I've written to remove the opening tag i.e. ${SOMETAG} but it doesn't seem to be able to find the tag. I think the problem is the pattern in my preg_match_all. Can you tell me what i did wrong here?

```
public function removeSearchPatterns()
{
    //search for ${*}
    preg_match_all(
        '/(${.*})/is',
        $this->tempDocumentMainPart,
        $matches,
        PREG_SET_ORDER
    );

    //remove ${*}
    foreach ($matches as $match){
        if (isset($match[0])) {
            $this->tempDocumentMainPart = str_replace(
                $match[0],
                '',
                $this->tempDocumentMainPart
            );
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you change the string pattern to '/\${\/?[a-zA-Z_-]*}/' works. This remove patterns like: namePattern, name-pattern, name_pattern and similars

Answer (score 0):

I did it! although suggestions for more efficient way are welcome.

```
public function removeSearchPatterns()
{
    //search for ${*} and ${/*} 
    preg_match_all(
        '/(\${)(\b[^}]*)(})(.*?)(\${.)(\2)(})/',
        $this->temporaryDocumentMainPart,
        $matches,
        PREG_SET_ORDER
    );
    //if ${*} and ${/*} are found, do the removal
    if (!empty($matches)){
        //remove ${*} and ${/*}
        foreach ($matches as $match){               
            if (isset($match[0])) {
                $this->temporaryDocumentMainPart = str_replace(
                    $match[0],
                    $match[4],
                    $this->temporaryDocumentMainPart
                );
            }
        }

        //search for <w:p> to </w:p>
        preg_match_all(
            '/(<w:p[^>]*><w:r[^>]*><w:t><\/w:t><\/w:r>)(?:<[^<>]+><[^<>]+>)?(<\/w:p>)/',
            $this->temporaryDocumentMainPart,
            $matches,
            PREG_SET_ORDER
        );

        //remove <w:p> to </w:p>
        foreach ($matches as $match){
            if (isset($match[0])) {             
                $this->temporaryDocumentMainPart = str_replace(
                    $match[0],
                    '',
                    $this->temporaryDocumentMainPart
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a method based on your code, but I simplify to remove only ${*} and ${/*}. By the way, thanks for the code above.

```
public function removeSearchPatterns()
{
    //search for ${*} and ${/*}
    preg_match_all(
        '/(\$\{[^\}]*\})/',
        $this->temporaryDocumentMainPart,
        $matches,
        PREG_SET_ORDER
    );

    //remove ${*} and ${/*}
    foreach ($matches as $match){
        $this->temporaryDocumentMainPart = str_replace(
            $match,
            '',
            $this->temporaryDocumentMainPart
        );
    }
}
```